# Steering and Ignition locked Alfa Romeo 1995 GTV Spider

Tags: ignition-switch, alfa-romeo, steering-lock

I’ve recently bought an old Alfa Romeo 1995 GTV spider with the intention of getting it back to working order. The issue at the moment is that the steering wheel is locked and the key won’t turn inside the ignition, except for backwards to turn on parking lights. The car does start, but due to the locked steering and ignition I have been unable to do so in the passed day. I think the locked steering was caused by me turning the wheel without the key in the ignition, I know, rookie error. However, I’m not sure why the ignition is locked. How should I go about fixing this?

Thank you,

Rufus

Comment: Is the steering "loading" the steering lock? Have you tried gently working the wheel while turning the key?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I have, that’s what I’ve read on various other websites, but doesn’t work as I can’t turn the key at all, even when turning the wheel the small amount to the right that it will go. Have tried all the suggested jiggle and putting the key just half way in and so on, no luck so far.